# How can I determine if the call recipient hangs up during a Twilio call in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio

I have the following simple callback to handle Twilio calls. I ask the user to press any keypad button to continue. If the call recipient doesn't press a key, the question is asked again. How can I determine if the call recipient hangs up. At present, if the call is answered and then hung-up, My redirect route continues the get hit until I give up asking to press any key. There can be a minute delay before the hangup and the point when my app stops receiving hits.

```
  def response
    Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
      r.Gather finishOnKey: '#', numDigits: @num_digits,
        timeout: @phone_wait_time,
        action: NGROK +
          voice_path(@notification.id, @final_question_response) do |g|
          g.Say @latest_question.text, voice: 'alice', language: 'en-AU'
      end
      r.Redirect NGROK +
        voice_redirect_path(@notification.id, @final_question_response)
    end.to_xml
  end
```

## EDIT

Here's a bit more information on the problem I have and what I'm trying to do. I'll use an example.

1) I make an outgoing call as follows

```
  def call_phone
    client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(
      Rails.application.secrets.twilio_sid,
      Rails.application.secrets.twilio_token
    )
    call = client.account.calls.create(
      from: Rails.application.secrets.twilio_voice_number,
      to: @phone_number,
      url: NGROK + question_path(@notification.id),
      method: 'GET',
      statusCallback: NGROK + call_status_path(@notification.id),
      statusCallbackEvent: [:initiated, :ringing, :answered, :completed]
    )
  end
```

2) My `statusCallback` is hit with the usual, `initiated`, `ringing` etc. The call recipient picks up the phone and the `statusCallback` is hit with `in-progress`. My `question_path` is hit as per the `url:` defined in 1 above. After some processing my response is called as follows

```
  def response
    Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
      r.Gather finishOnKey: '#', numDigits: @num_digits,
        timeout: @phone_wait_time,
        action: NGROK +
          voice_path(@notification.id, @final_question_response) do |g|
          g.Say @latest_question.text, voice: 'alice', language: 'en-AU'
      end
      r.Redirect NGROK +
        voice_redirect_path(@notification.id, @final_question_response)
    end.to_xml
  end
```

3) `@latest_question.text` says `Please press any key to continue`. If the call recipient hangs up, I would like to terminate the call. I was hoping my `statusCallback` would be hit with a status letting me know the call recipient has hung up. It doesn't do that and I don't know it has happened. After a timeout, my `voice_redirect_path` is hit. There is no response so I ask the question again. I still don't know the call has hung up. I continue asking the question and everything continues on as if the call recipient was still on the line. This continues on until I give up and hang up on the call. Then my `statusCallback` is hit with a status of `completed`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you set a `statusCallback` URL on the call, either from the API request on outbound or as the `statusCallback` setting for the number in the Twilio console?

Comment: Yes I have. The `statusCallback` continues to be hit with `in-progress` even though the call has hung up. It's not until I finally give up asking the caller to press any key and hang up myself that my `statusCallback` is hit with a `status` of `completed`.

Comment: I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24087517/twiml-app-if-the-caller-hangs-up-in-the-middle-of-the-application-process-does). It says I may be able to do what I want but doesn't actually say how I should do it.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve at this point? I feel like I need to know a little more context to solve this in a way that works for your application.

Comment: Please see edit above.

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

That's weird that you wouldn't immediately get a hangup event from the status callback. If you could email me at philnash@twilio.com with a call SID where this happens, I will raise it with the team internally (though I'm on holiday this week, so it might be quicker to go through the [support team](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact)).

To work around this, you could use a count parameter when you redirect to the `voice_redirect_path` and hang up yourself when the count reaches too high. Something like:

```
  def response
    Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
      @count = params[:count] || 0
      if @count > MAX_REDIRECTS
        r.Hangup
      else
        r.Gather finishOnKey: '#', numDigits: @num_digits,
          timeout: @phone_wait_time,
          action: NGROK +
            voice_path(@notification.id, @final_question_response) do |g|
            g.Say @latest_question.text, voice: 'alice', language: 'en-AU'
        end
        r.Redirect NGROK +
          voice_redirect_path(@notification.id, @final_question_response, :count = @count+1)
      end
    end.to_xml
  end
```

This would allow you to set a max number of redirects while waiting for an answer.

Let me know if this helps at all.